# Upgrade from pointers to references - How to deal with NULL to reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am new to C++11 and I have class like this:

```
class Pair; // defined somewhere...

class IReadOnlyList{
public:
        virtual const Pair *get(const char *key) const = 0;

        inline const Pair *operator[](const char *key) const{
                return get(key);
        };

        inline bool exists(const char *key) const{
                return get(key) != NULL;
        };
};
```

It working fine, but I want to remove pointers. However, if i change
`Pair *get()` to `Pair &get`, then I can not deal with non existent pairs.

Options are -
1. Exceptions
2. NULL-Object. Because Pair is POD (standard layout), I can use this at all.
3. return intermediate object, that encapsulate Pair * - sounds very dumb
4. Keeping NULL's :)

Is there any options I am missing?

Comment: If there's a chance of return a NULL then your code is just fine, references are of no use here. Initializing a reference with a NULL object is undefined behaviour (i.e., sky is the limit). One more advice since you use c++11, use smart pointers.

Comment: It may be an option to add IsDummy() method to Pair class and return a reference to the dummy Pair class when there is no object with the requested key.

Comment: @SergeRogatch - no such option because of POD, virtual methods are not allowed in Pair class.

Comment: Why can't you go the way STLs go and return an iterator (if bad, return the end() iterator) that "points" to the object if found.

Comment: @Nick, you don't need virtual methods. You need a dummy Pair object, which you can return a reference to and then, in the client code, you can test (where you would test for NULL) whether the returned object is dummy or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did check boost::optional, then I inspected the (future) experimental specification for std::optional and I come up with following:

https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM3/blob/master/std/std_container.h
and
https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM3/blob/master/std/std_optional.h

then because I will use it a lot, in where Pair is defined, I defined too:

```
class OPair : public std_optional<const Pair>{
public:
    OPair(const Pair *pair = nullptr) : std_optional(pair){};
};
```

Then IList::get() looks something like this:

```
const OPair IArray::get(const char *key) const override{
    uint64_t index;
    if (lookup(key, & index))
        return nullptr;  // LINE 1

    return _data[index]; // LINE 2
}
```

LINE 1 is NULL, it has been casted automatically to Pair *, then to OPair.
LINE 2 is returning Pair *, it been casted automatically to OPair.

using IList looks like:

```
OPair p = list.get("bla");
if (p){
   printf("%s\n", p->getVal());
   //or
   printf("%s\n", p().getVal());
   //or
   printf("%s\n", p.val().getVal());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Avoid pointers, as much as possible.

In such situation where a  function *might not* have a meaningful value to return, then `boost::optional` could be one solution:

```
virtual boost::optional<Pair> get(const char *key) const = 0;
```

Return an empty instance of `boost::optional<Pair>` when you dont have any meaningful value to return. The caller needs to check whether the returned `boost::optional<Pair>` is empty or holds an instance `Pair`.

---

Also, `find` seems to be a better name than `get` for such situation — as the function may or may not find a meaningful value with the associated `key`.

```
//return empty optional when no value found
virtual boost::optional<Pair> find(const char *key) const = 0;
```

If you want to keep `get` as function name, then throwing exception would be better solution:

```
//throw exception when no value found
virtual const Pair const& get(const char *key) const = 0;
```

You can have both function in your code — `get` can be implemented in terms of `find`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: what if he can't use boost?

Comment: @DavidHaim: Everyone should have such utility. If not boost, implement one yourself.

Comment: @DavidHaim - yes, people use boost for everything, however I like the solution with overloading * and I will try to hack it for my needs

Comment: `const` value returns are bad.

Comment: @Puppy:  It is  `const &`... and why is that bad? The function is declared to be `const`.

Comment: `const boost::optional<Pair>` no & here. And the function declared to be `const` and returning a `const` value are *completely orthogonal things*.

Comment: @Nawaz You probably meant `optional<const Pair&>`?

Comment: @Puppy: Ohh.. that was typo. I meant `boost::optional<Pair>` without any `const`.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Barry: No. I meant `boost::optional<Pair>`. Fixed it. Sorry for the confusion. (BTW, `optional<const Pair&>` does not make much sense to me).

Comment: @Nawaz Why not? If it's there, you get a reference-to-const. If it's not, you get nothing. You could make the non-const version `boost::optional<Pair&>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the expections  ARE the way to go. for some reasons people under-estimate their need.

If you can't throw exception what so ever, you can pass the result as reference and return bool to indiciate the function result - if it's true - the object that was passed as reference is valid as result, if false- handle the failure and don't use that object.

```
bool get(const char *key, Pair& pair) const{
   if (good){
     pair = goodObject;
     return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

but again, use exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way - to use an empty object.
Without knowing internal data members of Pair class, it cannot be exactly pointed which internal data member of Pair would serve this purpose but in a project we had used this approach of declaring public static constant object (for example Pair) which represents error or invalid situation.
The caller can check for some internal data member of that object(or call some safety method returning bool) to determine if the object is legitimate ir not.
It's not as elegant as exceptions or clean as NULL pointers but you can always return a valid object reference and also do away with the fear if the caller has handled the exception or not.

Comment: This is a terrible approach that should never have been invented. If you want an optional T, use boost::optional<T>, it's generic and also has the advantage of not being shit.

Comment: Everyone cannot use or does not have luxury to use Boost. The solution adheres to plain C++ language and I have seen it being used in poninterless libraries.

Comment: You mean, terrible pointerless libraries. Also, just so you know, boost::optional is written in plain C++ language. You can just write it yourself if you for some reason cannot depend upon Boost. It's no excuse to write terrible code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are returning a reference (pointer) and not (!) by value:

1. Exceptions:
   Are no good, if non-existing is a valid (non-exceptional) return value.
2. Null-Object:
   As you mentioned, a clumsy workaround.
3. Return intermediate object, that encapsulates the result:
   Would be an approach (see boost::optional), but you return a reference (pointer)
4. Keeping nullptr:
   Simple and smart in this situation. Making any usage not testing the return value for null undefined (not keeping a contract)

I don't think there is any smarter than 4.)

Comment: can you give me example with nullprt ?
I failed to found understandable example online.

Comment: @Nick nullptr (not nullprt) is the NULL you should use in C++11

Comment: Reference can not be set to nullptr?

Comment: Hi, may I ask you to see my answer and let me know what you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you return the Pair by value?  Thus, the values will be created on the stack, or wherever, and you won't have to worry about pointer leaks
and the like.

```
// Interface
Pair get (const char* key) const = 0;

... 

// Usage
Pair result = irp.get();

result.doSomething();
```

Thus, your get would look something like:

```
   Pair IRPointerClass::get (const char* key) 
   {
      Pair result;
      ... initialize result using key...
      return result;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside keeping the pointer and doing something stupid, here are all options with intermediate container class I can think of.

To be compile-able I created dummy Pair class and function instead of get() method.

**Note: I did not tried to deal with memory leaks here - please do not post comments about it...**

```
#include <stdio.h>

// This is Pair class

class Pair{
public:
    void print() const{
        printf("Hello\n");
    }
};

// This is Pair Container class,
// will be interesting to be rewritten with templates

class _Pair{
public:
    _Pair(const Pair *p = NULL) : _pair(p){};

    inline const Pair & val() const{
        return *_pair;
    }

    inline explicit operator bool() const {
        return _pair != NULL;
    }

    inline const Pair & operator *() const {
        return *_pair;
    }

    inline const Pair & operator ()() const {
        return *_pair;
    }

    inline const Pair * operator ->() const {
        return _pair;
    }

private:
    const Pair *_pair;
};

// this is GET() method

const _Pair & getPair(bool a){
    static const _Pair pnull = _Pair();

    if (a){
        return *new _Pair( new Pair() );
    }

    return pnull;
}

// this is usage

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const _Pair & p = getPair(false);

    if (p){
        p().print();
    }

    const _Pair & q = getPair(true);

    if (q){
        // option 1: nice, but additional ()
        // same as boost::optional
        (*q).print();

        // option 2: too long
        const Pair & pp = *q;
        pp.print();

        // option 3: no difference from pointer
        q->print();

        // option 4: using method - looks not bad
        // same as boost::optional
        q.val().print();

        // option 5: nive and yummy :)
        q().print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```